# Unknown type name 'CGVector'; did you mean 'CIVector'?

Tags: uikit, ios7, xcode5

I am working in a project i started in the last Xcode 4 version and when i open and try tu run it using the new Xcode 5 i get this error in both UIPushBehavior.h and UIGravityBehavior.h.

> /Applications/xcode 4/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIPushBehavior.h:34:34: Unknown type name 'CGVector'; did you mean 'CIVector'?

and does not compile my project.

Any ideas on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem here.
You said it works with iOS 7.0 target. As for me, it works with 6.1 but not with 7.0. Can you give more details ? Which UIKit framework version you used (6.1 / 7.0) ?
Did you had some imports in your project ? etc. TY

Comment: I started my project as a 4.6.3 XCode project, it compiled perfectly until XCode 5 5A1412 Build (GM Version) but on the 5A1413 (latest release) it stopped working. The problem relied on the fact that on my project i had the Header Search Path and the Library Search Path were pointing to the project directory , i believe this leaded the project to use  an older (6.1) version of UIKit . In my case i  fix the problem by changing  the Header Search Path to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include.  Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, i tried but still not working. I recreate a new project and it's working now. TY ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i fix the error.The problem relied on the Header Search Paths and the Library Search Path both were pointing to the project directories so the UIKit the project was using was an old one.

In my case i fix the problem by changing the Header Search Path to :
 **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/u‌​sr/include.**

and leaving the Library  search path pointing to my project folder:

**$(SRCROOT)/project_name**

Tricky one since it compiled in any version prior to XCode 5 5A1413.

Hope this helps to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

[CGVector is part of CGGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH202-SW1).

To fix your problem, make certain the ApplicationServices framework is included in your project and also "`#import <CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h>`" at the top of your .m file.

Oh, looking closely at the documentation, I see CGVector was made available as of iOS 7 and later.  This means you might have a conflicting type in your project if something else was defining it prior to you using Xcode 5.

Comment: ApplicationServices framework is only available for MacOS not iOS

Comment: you're right... I was looking at the iOS documentation on developer.apple.com and it incorrectly pointed me at the ApplicationServices framework.  I've fixed that up.  Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it looked more like a bug since the errors I were getting, were located in the UIPushBehavior.h of the UIKit framework. While i was trying to figure stuff out I ran the app using iOS 7 Deployment Target instead of a 6.1 and that seemed to fix the error. Thanks