# Error when trying to run the project on real device (iPhone 8.2)

Tags: ios, xcode

No similar problems when I run the project on simulator.

[image]

EDITED:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your device on iOS8 ? CGVector is only available since iOS8

Edit : [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071014/unknown-type-name-cgvector-did-you-mean-civector)

> In my case i fix the problem by changing the Header Search Path to : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/u‌​sr/include.
>
> and leaving the Library search path pointing to my project folder:
>
> $(SRCROOT)/project_name

Comment: And check please too my question (After changes paths)

Comment: You probably messed up with paths, double check them, and if needed validate them by checking in Finder